# Excel autofill shortcut with range deduction

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the following Excel spreadsheet, I'm active in cell C2 and want to copy the formula down to C11. How can I achieve that with the keyboard? Most answers seem to begin with "highlight the range you need", but doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> takes me down to the end of the spreadsheet. However, if I double click the drag handle in the corner of the cell, it deduces the range correctly.

[image: Link to picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a magic copy-down keyboard shortcut in Excel.

I would hit

1. <kbd>←</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to jump to the bottom of the adjacent range
3. <kbd>→</kbd>
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to select the fill range
5. then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to fill down.

If you're a keyboard-first user, this is pretty quick even though it's 5 steps.